# Group by , sort by and difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me derive formula to calculate the difference in Excel after group by and sort by, [image]

In the above excel want to group the columns values "Process Unit,Process Name" and sort by "Time", and find difference between values using Time

Expected:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you ask is coming across. If you do a sumif() for all processes, then the result will be the same irrespective of order.

Comment: In the second image the value derived row2-row1, please see expected image

Comment: You say it is after group by, but the info is not grouped. How will the starting data be?

Comment: @Moacir: I didn't group it, it is the actual data

Comment: The first result of 10 is 770 - 760, ok. But the second result of 20 is not 850 - 770... You need to clarify exactly what you have to start with and the results you expect.

Comment: @SolarMike: The second result is 790-770 in by grouping Unit1 and process1 and sorted by time

Comment: @Antguider I get that it is the actual data, but you mentioned you need the formula AFTER the group and sort. Formulas work differently depending on how the data is

Comment: @Moacir: I am not good at excel terms, I need to find the "Difference" in dynamic way

Comment: It is not an excel term thing. Do you also need help sorting the data?

Comment: @Moacir: I need the second image as output

Comment: @Antguider Ok. The data will be unsorted, but the answer has to be the difference after a "pseudo-sorting"?

Comment: @Moacir: Yes ...

Comment: So use sumifs() and criteria of unit & process number & time finding the most recent, then find the one just prior to the most recent and calculate the difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TEXTJOIN` or just use `&` to join columns A and B together to "group" your criteria into column C.

Use `VLOOKUP` and look at only the data underneath the row which holds the following formula: `VLOOKUP(<my column C value>, <data underneath this row>, <my 'current value' row>, <FALSE - exact match only>) - <this row's current value>)`

[image: example]